# defining print pattern of a string

Tags: python, string

```py
def print_string(ABC):
   
    for r in range(7):
        for cur_char in ABC:
            for c in range(6):
                print(cur_char[r,c],end="")
        print("")
```

`TypeError: string indices must be integers`

I have tried nothing yet.

Comment: What is `ABC` and what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Substring in Python uses `:` as separators. The correct syntax goes like

```py
string[start:end:step] # From start to end (exclusive) each step-th
                       # character (meaning 0th, 2nd, 4th ... for step=2)
string[start:]         # From start
string[:end]           # From 0 to end (exclusive)
```

So in your case:

```py
print(cur_char[r:c],end="")
```

More on substrings in Python: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-substring-a-string-in-python/